# Does Armored Core: Verdict Day have active players?

Tags: armored-core-5

I was surprised by how no one was online on Armored Core V when i got my hands on it. Is Armored Core: Verdict Day the same way for xbox 360 version?
Does it have any players that play online or would it take me hours to find someone for a multiplayer match?

Comment: This was flagges as 'opinion-based'. I disagree. The quiestion in the tittle may be, but the question in the body about the size of the current online playerbase would not be.

Comment: Was it flagged as "opinion-based" really? It is clearly a question whether or not multiplayer is dead.

Comment: I'd say that was propably for the tittle question.

Comment: Where do i see if its flagged by the way

Comment: The flag seems to be cleared by now, most likely by clearing the review queue. You should be able to click on both flagging and closing link to see how many times each reason has been selected.

Comment: The only objective part of this that we could answer is, *maybe*, the number of people that play it online.  Whether it has a future or not very much is opinion based.  If you want to limit the question to figuring out how many people are playing it online, I think we can keep that.  But currently, as it stands, I would definitely close it.

Comment: Edited. Hope this helps.